# HTML - Navigation Bars and Webpage Code

Tags: html, css

Okay, so hello everyone. I am seeking help on something I don't quite understand. I am new to HTML, CSS and am wondering about the simple question of this.

In my website if the user selects the 'sign in' tab. It should redirect them to a page where they can fill in their existing user/password or create a new account if necessary.

My question is, when they have signed in, what do I do so instead of it showing "Sign In" on my navbar, but how do I replace it without it not being removed altogether?

Sorry if this is hard to understand, please let me know if you would like any questions to be asked about my problem.

An example:
When you log into stack overflow, when you are successfully logged in there is no option to sign into your account, is it a different webpage overall when your signed in or how does it work?

Comment: can you create a snippet with relevant code?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: You should think of storing the account in a location that you may access wherever : a database (or a no-sql document). Without this, you could not rely on data stored in user web browser.

Comment: @silviagreen https://jsfiddle.net/d7z5Lm9f/ there is a jsfiddle of my website, if you notice at the top right it says "sign in" after the user has signed in, how do I get rid of the sign in option and display something else. Thanks

Comment: @Zeratops I know about databases and such, it's just the HTML I am struggling with

Answer (score 0):

There would generally be a server language used with a website that has a login feature, most commonly PHP.

With PHP your server can save variables, that contain information, such as if a user is currently logged in.

Then you can write conditional statements that offer different output, depending on the condition. For example:

`if (user_logged_in()) { echo "Hello ".$user."!"; } else { echo "Login"; }`

This line basically says, if the user is logged in, then display Hello and their username. If they are not logged in, then display 'Login'.

That's a very simple form, but that's how it would be done, essentially all using PHP IF statements - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php

Comment: Thank you for this, how would I link this to the HTML & Website in general. Sorry again, I'm new so I apologize if I make no sense.

Comment: Well you've got a LONG way to go from a HTML website. You'll need a database, PHP on your server, and a good understanding of how simple PHP works. This is not something that can be added to a simple HTML static website.